# Building script to access public Twitter data, without authentication

Tags: python, twitter

I would like to write a script in Python to read a public Twitter profile. Specifically, I'd like to check for Tweets with images, and download those images (eventually, I'd like to add this as a cron job). I was looking into **tweepy** as a Twitter API wrapper. However, from what I understand, the Twitter API requires authentication even for actions that access public data - is that correct?

Since all I need is to access a single public user timeline, going through the rigmarole of authenticating (and then having those credentials sitting on my computer in I'm not sure how secure a form) seems a little overkill.

Are there other solutions out there (particularly Python-based) for reading public Twitter data?

Comment: Twitter recommends us to create an app, which has an username password for authentication, then using that app we can query the Twitter API service to get the required data, If twitter doesn't enforces this username/password constraint then people can simply spam their servers, with ambiguous identities. So this enforcement doesn't comes from `Tweepy` but it is recommended way of doing things. However if you want you can bypass this and write a simple web scrapper, But I would recommend creating a Twitter app.

Comment: I understood that it's Twitter's requirement, not Tweepy's. Thanks for clarifying some of the reasoning behind it. Maybe I'll consider doing it the proper way after all, since reinventing the wheel by scraping the bare html doesn't sound all that attractive either.

Comment: @ZdaR Please write up your comment as an answer. Your explanation of Twitter's policy is pretty much what I was looking for before asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Twitter does require, authentication to access any public/private data of user. You need to create an app on Twitter to access the data. The app is required to keep a check on the number of requests, etc. made by a particular client, to prevent any abuse. This authentication is a general process followed by other API providers as well and this is the only recommended way.

Another advantage of creating a Twitter App is that other users can give permissions to your app and then you can access their private data as well such as DM, etc.

Another approach is web-scraping, but I would consider it as unethical as twitter is already providing it's API. Also you would need to update your scraping script each time there is some front end change by the Twitter developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create your own data scraper. `BeautifulSoup` is a popular one. For example something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen('https://twitter.com/Microsoft')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser');
print(soup)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly"/> ......................
```

Comment: This is a great answer to get me started building a web scraper. However, accepted answer explained the reasoning behind the authentication requirement and why the web scraper alternative is not great - which while it might appear secondary to my original question, was really the answer I was looking for. Wish I could accept both.

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for one time thing, scraper would work, but in the long term, you would need to modify things.